# what is comparative philosophy?

Tags: metaphilosophy

Nowadays we  are confronted  with a new major as comparative philosophy..Paul Mason Orsel the French philosopher has a book by the very name..my question is that what kind of philosophy is comparative philosophy? At all could existed such a philosophy?

Comment: Have you really not even tried to [google the term](https://www.google.ru/search?q=comparative+philosophy&oq=comparative+philosophy&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)? And also, why exactly do you think that such philosophy cannot exist?

Comment: @132181: I Google it but I find nothing benefit me..I can't determine  what kind of philosophy is as comparative..in fact I want to know if such a philosophy existed then what are its determiners and traits..

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you elaborate more? What you've written doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: it is simple: what  is the meaning of comparative here? Is it a kind of method? What is the exact meaning of the expression.. For instance continental philosophy  or analytic have the same meaning as comparative..at all comparative philosophy is familiar with which philosophies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the term comparative philosophy refers to the task of comparing two philosophies across different traditions rather than making comparisons simpliciter or say looking at the relationship between thinkers in one tradition.

I'd try looking at a paper by [Ralph Weber](https://uzh.academia.edu/RalphWeber) who is an expert in this area.